# TFS 2013 - check in policy - require a specific work item type

Tags: tfs, checkin

Is it possible to create a check in policy that enforces developers to associate a specific work item type, like User Story, for example? We are using TFS 2013 here.

Thanks!
Vítor

Answer (score 0):

If you install the power tools you get a work item query policy.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

I usually create a query that shows only Tasks that are assigned to @me and use that.